# How to automatically start a service after manually decrypting /home partition

Tags: mount, encryption, services, systemd, dmcrypt

**Problem:** 
I have a service,`seafile.service`, that automatically starts a Seafile server after boot. However, this service is failing to start on my Ubuntu server that has an encrypted `/home` partition. The service requires access to the `/home/sfadmin/seafile/seafile-server-latest/seafile.sh` as shown in [this guide](https://manual.seafile.com/deploy/start_seafile_at_system_bootup.html).

The service fails to automatically start the Seafile server even after manual decryption of the `/home` partition. When I manually start the service by doing `sudo systemctl start seafile.service`, it works, however, I am asked for decryption passphrase for `/home` partition even though the partition is already decrypted and mounted. Even if I input a wrong passphrase, the service will start without issues.

**Background:**

1. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS server with an encrypted `/home` partition. The `/home` partition is encrypted using DMCrypt (cryptsetup). I used [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/DetailedProcess) to encrypt my `/home` partition.
2. My `/etc/fstab` is configured with `nofail` directive for my `/home` partition as follows: `/dev/mapper/data-home /home           ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2`
3. My `/etc/crypttab` is configured as follows: `data   UUID=myuuidhere none   luks,discard,noearly,nofail`
4. Decryption of my `/home` partition is done manually. After every boot, I remotely decrypt the `/home` partition using SSH with the command `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 data`.
5. After decryption, Ubuntu automatically mounts the `/home` partition.

**Attempted solution**

Since the Seafile service (`/etc/systemd/system/seafile.service`) requires access to the `/home` partition, I used the follow directives for my service configuration: `ConditionPathExists`, `Requires`, and `After`. Below is my exact service definition.

```
[Unit]
Description=Seafile
ConditionPathExists=/home/sfadmin
Requires=home.mount
# add mysql.service or postgresql.service depending on your database to the line below
After=network.target mysql.service home.mount

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/sfadmin/seafile/seafile-server-latest/seafile.sh start
ExecStop=/home/sfadmin/seafile/seafile-server-latest/seafile.sh stop
User=sfadmin
Group=sfadmin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Issue:**

After the Ubuntu server is rebooted, I remotely login using SSH and manually decrypt the `/home` partition. I confirmed that the `/home` partition is automatically mounted, however, the `seafile.service` still fails to start due to dependencies.

When I manually try to start the seafile.service using the command `sudo systemctl start seafile.service`, I get prompted for passphrase to decrypt the `/home` partition even though it is already decrypted. When asked for the passphrase, I leave it blank and press enter, and I don't get another prompt. When I check the status of the `seafile.service`, it is now started and active.

I think the possible culprit of `seafile.service` not being able to start could be related to the system asking for a passphrase to decrypt the `/home` partition even though it is already decrypted.

**Why is the system asking for the passphrase when starting `seafile.service` manually when `/home` partition is already decrypted?**

See the steps below:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 data
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3:
$ sudo systemctl status seafile.service
● seafile.service - Seafile
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/seafile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 10 04:14:02 VM-SERVER systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Seafile.
Mar 10 04:14:02 VM-SERVER systemd[1]: seafile.service: Job seafile.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
$ sudo systemctl start seafile.service
Please enter passphrase for disk data!
$ sudo systemctl status seafile.service
● seafile.service - Seafile
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/seafile.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-03-10 04:36:46 EST; 11s ago
  Process: 1589 ExecStart=/home/sfadmin/seafile/seafile-server-latest/seafile.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 15
   Memory: 21.2M
      CPU: 528ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/seafile.service
           ├─1614 /home/sfadmin/seafile/seafile-server-6.2.5/seafile/bin/seafile-controller -c /home/sfadmin/seafile/ccnet -d /home/sfadmin/seafile/seafile-data -F /home/sfadmin/seafile/conf
           ├─1616 ccnet-server -F /home/sfadmin/seafile/conf -c /home/sfadmin/seafile/ccnet -f /home/sfadmin/seafile/logs/ccnet.log -d -P /home/sfadmin/seafile/pids/ccnet.pid
           └─1618 seaf-server -F /home/sfadmin/seafile/conf -c /home/sfadmin/seafile/ccnet -d /home/sfadmin/seafile/seafile-data -l /home/sfadmin/seafile/logs/seafile.log -P /home/sfadmin/seafile/pids/seaf-server.pid

Mar 10 04:36:42 VM-SERVER systemd[1]: Starting Seafile...
Mar 10 04:36:43 VM-SERVER seafile.sh[1589]: [03/10/18 04:36:43] ../common/session.c(132): using config file /home/sfadmin/seafile/conf/ccnet.conf
Mar 10 04:36:43 VM-SERVER seafile.sh[1589]: Starting seafile server, please wait ...
Mar 10 04:36:46 VM-SERVER systemd[1]: Started Seafile.
```